# Ciclo FOR solo me recorre indice 0 en Nodesj

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, bucle-for

Tengo una *query* la cual me arroja varios id , 
lo que quiero realizar en que con un ciclo me recorra todas las id y me las muestre en un `array`, lo intento con el ciclo `for` pero solo me recorre el indice 0 del `recorset`

**CODIGO**

```
resultados = result.recordset;
var valores = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.recordset.length; i++) {
    console.log(resultados[i]);
    valores = resultados[i].idMenuXPerfil;
}
```

Esto me trae a la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero que me recorra estos datos en un `array`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo me muestra el 10

Comment: ¿Has verificado que `result.recordset` tenga más de 1 registro? Antes de entrar en el bucle puedes hacer un `console.log(result.recordset.length)` a ver que te arroja. Saludos

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras es probable que `result.recordset` tenga sólo 1 registro, lo que veo también es que en la línea `valores = resultados[i].idMenuXPerfil;` estás pisando el resultado anterior de la variable, en lugar de asignar deberías hacer un `push`, algo como esto `valores.push(resultados[i].idMenuXPerfil)`

Comment: deberias poner tu ejemplo funcional en un jsfiddle.net o algo para poder ver lo q tu estas experimentando y poderte ayudar con el tema, por ahora te diria que puedes usar el .map() para hacer lo q necesitas